pilot fields distance in DVB S2X superframe format 2
According to the standard, dvb s2x superframe format 2 contains 639 36-symbol p-pilot fields repeated every 956 symbols (from the beginning of the pilot field to the beginning of the next pilot field), where the first pilot field starts at symbol 1665.
A DVB-S2X superframe format 2 contains 9 bundled PL-Frames each contains 71 36-symbol p-pilot fields, a 64800-symbol data payload, 384-symbol PLH, and 180-symbol P2-pilot field. The payload data is separated by the p-pilot fields
The superframe also has 270-symbol SOSF and 450-symbol SFFI as a preamble.
From the above information, and to maintain the 956 symbol separation between the p-pilot field, the first "payload field" in the first bundled PL frame has to be of length 380 symbols, and the next 70 "payload fields" each of length 920, and the last "payload field" is of length 20 symbols.
But then the distance from the last p-pilot field of bundled PL-frame 1 to the first p-pilot field in bundled PL frame 2 will be:









   36
last p-pilot field in bundled PL-frame 1


+  20
last payload field in bundled PL-frame 1


+ 384
PLH of bundled PL-frame 2


+ 180
p2-pilot field of bundled PL-frame 2


+ 380
1st payload field of bundled PL-frame 2 if we need to maintain the same bundled PL-frame structure for the 9 bundled PL frames


=1000
and not 956



My question is: is this 956-symbol distance is met only within a bundled PL frame, or across the whole superframe?
